# Get length of components of a multilinestring

Tags: r, sf

I am looking to get **not** the length of the **overall** `multilinestring` but rather the length of the **component parts**. Here is what I have so far:

```
library(sf)

s1 <- rbind(c(0,3),c(0,4),c(1,5),c(2,5))
s2 <- rbind(c(0.2,3), c(0.2,4), c(1,4.8), c(2,4.8))
s3 <- rbind(c(0,4.4), c(0.6,5))
mls <- st_multilinestring(list(s1,s2,s3))

# calculate overall length
st_length(mls)

# split multilinestring into component linestring objects
mls_points <- st_cast(mls, "MULTIPOINT")
mls_split <- st_split(mls, mls_points)

plot(mls)
plot(mls_points, add = TRUE, col = "red")

# error on length of split output
st_length(mls_split)
```

> Error: inherits(x, "sfc_LINESTRING") || inherits(x, "sfc_MULTILINESTRING") is not TRUE

[image]

Maybe there is something I am supposed to be doing with `st_cast`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an `sfc` first, then use `st_cast`, which will split it into LINESTRINGs:

```
> st_length(st_cast(st_sfc(mls),"LINESTRING"))
[1] 3.4142136 3.1313708 0.8485281
```

these sum to `st_length(mls)`.

Took some digging to figure this out, the help wasn't helpful:

> the ‘st_cast’ method for ‘sf’ objects can only split geometries,
>        e.g. cast ‘MULTIPOINT’ into multiple ‘POINT’ features.

until I realised it said "for `sf` objects" and you didn't have a `sf` object, you had an `sfg` object. Not sure why `st_cast` doesn't split those but the solution is fairly simple once you know!

Comment: I plotted the results at: https://gist.github.com/jsta/4528b5d845467479957ffb99954a1484 to prove to myself that it works.

Comment: If your object is an sf data frame than you need something like `st_length(st_cast(st_sfc(mls$geom), "LINESTRING"))`

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't very elegant, but

```
# split multilinestring into component linestring objects and then to points
mls_pts <- st_sfc(mls) %>%
  st_cast(., 'LINESTRING') %>%
  lapply(., function(x) {
    st_sfc(x) %>% 
      st_cast(., 'POINT')})

# get distances between points
mls_seglengths <- lapply(mls_pts, function(d) {
  start <- 1:(length(d)-1)
  end   <- 2:length(d)
  dists <- mapply(function(a,b) {st_distance(d[a], d[b])}, a = start, b = end)
})
```

Comment: Nice work! I think I misled you a bit with the figure. @Spacedman had the solution I was after.

Comment: hah yeah I was bored at work and overshot the mark :P. That sf/sfc/sfg divide really needs more clarification too...